# How to make docky and gnome shell work together?

Tags: gnome, notification, docky, notification-area

I like gnome shell and I like docky. The problem is that the gnome shell places the notifications and that little notification dock down there. I want to place docky at the bottom but then the notifications interfere with it. Is it possible to move (off possible) everything related to the no fixations to the panel and/or the top right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Left/Middle-message-tray](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/157/left-message-tray/) Gnome shell extension to get the notification area out of the way.